# How to change style of clicked element and current element?

Tags: javascript

I want to change the class of the clicked element and remove the class from the "current" element. My current code works aswell, but I'm looking for a cleaner / automatic way. So I'm looking for a way to say something like: remove class from all existing elements and add it to the clicked one (this).

My current `code`:

```js
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').addEventListener('click', showForm1);
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').addEventListener('click', showForm2);
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').addEventListener('click', showForm3);
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').addEventListener('click', showForm4);
 
 function showForm1(){
    this.classList.add('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').classList.remove('activetab');
  }
  function showForm2(){
    this.classList.add('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').classList.remove('activetab');

  }
  function showForm3(){
    this.classList.add('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').classList.remove('activetab');
  }
  function showForm4(){
    this.classList.add('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').classList.remove('activetab');
    document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').classList.remove('activetab');
  }
```

```html
<div style="display:  flex;">
 <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
  </div>
  </div>
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: You might aswell remove the CSS from your post. It's not really relevant to your question.

Comment: Okay, thought it'd be useful to actually see it change in snippet, but will remove it :)

Comment: It would be useful - otherwise we can't check if the "activetab" class works properly!

Comment: Yeah, I just realized that. Apologies.

Comment: You could add all relevant elements to an array. When you change the tab, first iterate over the array to remove the class and finally add it to the relevant class. Wrap that in a function.

Comment: :D no worries  One thing though, if only one DIV is set with activetab, how is the user going to click on any of the others?

Comment: @AlphaWolfGamer that's not how SO works...

Comment: @ATD activetab only changes the style of the current tab. What is missing in this code is these are button tabs to show a form beneath the tabs. So activetab shows which form is showing atm.

Comment: Sorry - I did update the css to include that: `.form-tabs-submit.activetab > span`

Comment: why remove `span` element from `div.form-tabs-submit` div ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You `code` can simplified to just few lines using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) method.

Firstly get all elements by its remove all `activeTab` classes from the tabs. Add only to the clicked element using [Event.Target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)

```
let getTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-tabs-submit')

getTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function(e) { //attach event Listener
    getTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
      tab.classList.remove('activetab') //remove from all tabs
    })
    e.target.classList.add('activetab') //add Class to clicked tab only
  })
})
```

**Live Demo:**

```js
let getTabs = document.querySelectorAll('.form-tabs-submit')

getTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
  tab.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    getTabs.forEach(function(tab) {
      tab.classList.remove('activetab')
    })
    e.target.classList.add('activetab')
  })
})
```

```css
.form-tabs-submit {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #0000000F;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #707070;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-tabs-submit.activetab {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-tabs-submit::first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px
}

.form-tabs-submit::last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I feel like this is the cleanest and simplest way, going to use this for sure. Thanks!

Comment: @Sybrentjuh Thank you - Happy to hear that. Let me if you need any other help. I will be happy to help. Happy coding :)

Comment: I actually do need some more help haha. I have implemented this. But in my code above I left out some part. The div's actually look like this: 
<div class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 oktober</span>
  </div> So they have a subtitle span in the tab. When I click on the subtitle, it removes the activetab from current one, but doesnt add it to the target. It only works when I click anywhere but on the subtitle.

Comment: @Sybrentjuh no problem :)  use this in that case => `e.currentTarget.classList.add('activetab')` - just add that instead of `e.target.classList.add('activetab')` and here is working jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3fzcxesq/

Comment: Thanks! I thought of a css solution aswell just after you responded, I added 'pointer-events: none' to the subtitle, so that it doesn't fire click events.

Comment: @Sybrentjuh yeah sure - that CSS would do the trick but this way will be more cleaner as well :)

Comment: Okay, then I will use that :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222020/discussion-between-sybrentjuh-and-always-helping).

Answer (score 3):

You can optimize your code in the following way:

```js
//Get all the tabs starting id with hotelgids-tab-
var all = document.querySelectorAll('[id^=hotelgids-tab-]');
//Loop through them to attch the click event
all.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', showForm));
function showForm(e){
  //Remove class from all
  all.forEach((el) => el.closest('div').classList.remove('activetab'));
  //Add the class to the clicked tab
  e.target.closest('div').classList.add('activetab');
}
```

```css
.form-tabs-submit {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #0000000F;
  border-radius:0px;
  color: #707070;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .form-tabs-submit.activetab {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius:0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
```

```html
<div style="display:  flex;">
 <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 oktober</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 december</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 januari</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 maart</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
document.getElementsBySelector('.form-tabs-submit').addEventListener('click', activateElement); // Listen to every element by class instead of each one by id

 
function activateElement(currentElement) {
    // Disable all elements
    var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-tabs-submit');
    allElements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.remove('activetab');
    }

    // Activate the current element
    currentElement.classList.add('activetab');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').addEventListener('click', changecollorofme);
document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').addEventListener('click', changecollorofme);
document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').addEventListener('click', changecollorofme);
document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').addEventListener('click', changecollorofme);

function changecollorofme() {
  // Disable all elements
var allElements = document.querySelectorAll('.form-tabs-submit');
allElements.forEach(function(element) {
    element.classList.remove('activetab');
}
  this.classList.add('activetab');
}
```

```css
.form-tabs-submit {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #0000000F;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #707070;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-tabs-submit.activetab {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-tabs-submit::first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px
}

.form-tabs-submit::last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:  flex;">
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
    <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 oktober</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
    <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 december</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
    <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 januari</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
    <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 maart</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

I made it tidy

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-1').addEventListener('click', function(){showMe(this)});
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-2').addEventListener('click', function(){showMe(this)});
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-3').addEventListener('click', function(){showMe(this)});
 document.getElementById('hotelgids-tab-4').addEventListener('click', function(){showMe(this)});
 function showMe(d) {
  let thisDiv = d.id;
  let allItems = document.getElementById("hotelgids").querySelectorAll("div");
  allItems.forEach(function(g) {
    if (g.id == thisDiv) {
      g.classList.remove("inactivetab");
      g.classList.add("activetab");
    } else {
      g.classList.remove("activetab");
      g.classList.add("inactivetab");
    }
  })
 
 }
```

```css
.form-tabs-submit {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #0000000F;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #707070;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.form-tabs-submit.activetab > span{
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-tabs-submit.inactivetab > span{
  display: none;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius: 0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.form-tabs-submit:first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px
}

.form-tabs-submit:last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
}

span {display:block}
```

```html
<div id="hotelgids" style="display:flex;">
 <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 oktober</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit inactivetab width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 december</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit inactivetab width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 januari</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit inactivetab hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 maart</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

I've added an id to the outer div to allow me to loop through the inner ones.  I've also added a style called `inactivetab` which sets `display:none`

Comment: I would also do the addEventListener statements in a loop and use a variable name to identify each one, but I've left them as individual instructions - though, I have changed the actual function being triggered to use `this`

Comment: I have just added a comment about that!

Answer (score 0):

I would try with this solution:

```js
var maxForms = 4;

for(var i=0; i<maxForms; i++) {
  var elementName = 'hotelgids-tab-' + (i+1);
  document.getElementById(elementName).addEventListener('click', createShowForm(i));
}

function createShowForm(num) {
    return function showForm() {
        for(let i=0; i<maxForms; i++) {
            var elementName = 'hotelgids-tab-' + (i+1);
            document.getElementById(elementName).classList.remove('activetab');
        }
        this.classList.add('activetab');
    }
}
```

```css
.form-tabs-submit {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #0000000F;
  border-radius:0px;
  color: #707070;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
 .form-tabs-submit.activetab {
  display: flex;
  background: #FFFFFF 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #00000029;
  border-radius:0px;
  color: #EC008C;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #EC008C;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 9px 0px;
  font-size: 16px;
 }
 .form-tabs-submit::first-of-type {
  border-radius: 4px 0px 0px 0px
 }
 .form-tabs-submit::last-of-type {
  border-radius: 0px 4px 0px 0px;
 }
```

```html
<div style="display:  flex;">
 <div id="hotelgids-tab-1" class="form-tabs-submit activetab width-33">Avro Bode
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 oktober</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-2" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 december</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-3" class="form-tabs-submit width-33">Avro Kro NCRV
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 januari</span>
  </div>
  <div id="hotelgids-tab-4" class="form-tabs-submit hotelgids-3">Vara Tros Mikro
   <span class="hotelgids-subtitle">Acties geldig t/m 31 maart</span>
  </div>
  </div>
```

The maxForms variable tells how many forms you handle in the grid.