# On click add class to hide other elements using vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

At the moment when the user clicks one of the SVGs the class "clicked" is added to that particular SVG. What I would like to happen is that when an SVG is clicked on the page, the other SVG elements are hidden (opacity: 0 or something) and not clickable.

My JS knowledge is a bit limited. I was thinking a class would need to be added to the SVGs when the others were inactive as I was thinking about transitioning them out when a click happens, however would appreciate any suggestions.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Interactive SVG</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/styles.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container" id="container">
      <svg version="1.0" class="svg svg-a" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect class="rect rect-a" width="100" height="100" />
      </svg>
      <svg version="1.0" class="svg svg-b" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect class="rect rect-b" width="100" height="100" />
      </svg>
      <svg version="1.0" class="svg svg-c" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
        <rect class="rect rect-c" width="100" height="100" />
      </svg>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/animejs@3.0.1/lib/anime.min.js"></script>
    <script src="static/js/script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #222;
  position: relative;
}

svg {
  display: flex;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 0.7s ease-out;
}

.rect {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #eee;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.rect-a {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
  z-index: 390;
}

.rect-b {
  fill: pink;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}

.rect-c {
  fill: azure;
  box-shadow: 20px 20px 20px 0;
}

.clicked {
  fill: cornflowerblue;
  transform: scale(1.2);
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transition: 0.5s;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

.clicked svg {
  fill: red;
  transform: translateY(500px);
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
  color: red;
  top: -5px;
  right: -5px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  z-index: 900;
}
```

```
// First we get all the path elements and put them in an array
let paths = document.getElementsByClassName('svg');

// Now we can loop over the array and add an eventlistener to each path in the array and it listens to the 'click' event and then runs function toggleClass()
for (let i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
  paths[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClass);
}

// In the function toggleClass we can toggle the 'clicked' class.
function toggleClass() {
  this.classList.toggle('clicked');
}
```

https://codepen.io/chrismorrison/pen/ZEWdJyV

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change style of clicked element and current element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046659/how-to-change-style-of-clicked-element-and-current-element)

Comment: This helps, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated [CodePen](https://codepen.io/art-form/pen/BazBLOR) w/ rough implementation of what I believe you are looking for.

Below are the changes I made:

## JS

```
// In the function toggleClass we can toggle the 'clicked' class.
function toggleClass(e) {
  const clickedClassName = 'clicked';
  
  // If "disabled", don't respond to the click event.
  if(this.classList.contains('disabled')) {
    e.preventDefault();
  } 
  // The element is "enabled".  Has it been clicked
  // already?  If so, we need to restore it along with
  // all the other SVGs back to their original state.
  // If not, then hide all other SVGs and add the "clicked"
  // class to the element that was clicked
  else if(!this.classList.contains(clickedClassName)) {
    this.classList.add(clickedClassName);
    
    for(let p of paths) {
      if(this !== p) {
        toggleDisabled(p)
      }
    }
  } else {
    this.classList.remove(clickedClassName);
    
    for(let p of paths) {
      if(this !== p) {
        toggleDisabled(p)
      }
    }
  }
}

function toggleDisabled(p) {
  p.classList.contains('disabled') ? p.classList.remove('disabled') : p.classList.add('disabled')
}
```

## CSS

```
.disabled {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

Comment: Depending on which class is `clicked` I am looking to animate out the other blocks. Is it possible to have the classes as `clicked-one`, `clicked-two`, `clicked-three` etc.? I can't figure out what JavaScript function would allow me to do this.